# Cannot download ".config" files from host via http

Tags: c#, http-status-code-404, clickonce, app-config, publish

I've published my ClickOnce application to my website via FTP.
I've got 404 error (not found) when run "app.application". In log file there is a line that says cannot find "app.exe.config" file.
I noticed that I can access to this file via FTP and online file manager of website, but when I try to use HTTP, this error is shown.
I've created new files with different names on website (all of them have .config or .cfg extension), but result is the same: I cannot access them via HTTP (through address bar of browser).
I am using a windows web hosting server and it has a "web.config" file in the root folder of website.
Should I do any change in server settings or I must rename my .config file?
any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `.config` is normally a security risk and can be blocked by many security systems. I'd check to make sure you don't have something like URLScan on the server or a firewall blocking the connection.

Comment: I don't think any software is running on server. I think it is because of server policy and I have only 2 solutions: 1. Rename the file 2. Exclude this file from policy check on server. Also I don't know how to do both of them! any other solutions?